# Div positioned absolute not showing up in firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox, cross-browser, positioning

I have a div (#socmed) with an ul containing li's which i have positioned at the top right of my page. You can find the div inside the header tag. These are social media buttons by the way.

http://digilabs.be/tutu/collection.php

As you can see, it only shows up in chrome and safari (haven't tested in IE yet).

I have tried changing the z-index, because I felt like it got overlapped by the parent div, which is colored pink. But that didn't seem to work. I have no idea what to do.

Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: Throw some code up so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main.css:Line 73`

Add a width to the `<li>` item.

```
#socmed li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 25px; /* Add this width..! */
}
```

This seems to fix your problem.

Your outer `#socmed` div has `width: 25px`, but your `<li>` within it does not, and by default it is larger then the `25px` as specified on `#socmed`, so would not display.

Comment: :) - Please accept the answer by clicking the `tick` below the vote count, glad I could help!

Comment: What is perhaps more interesting is how the problem arose in the first place.  The OP is using the twitter bootstrap CSS framework and ran into a styling conflict with a pre-existing declaration on the ul, ol rule.

Answer (score 1):

2 CSS adjustments you can make.  First make a relative container (not fully tested on your page, but usually a good practice...

```
header  {
position:relative;
}
```

Second, define a width for your ul list items in your header...

```
#socmed ul {
width:30px;
}
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunately the div still isn't visible to the user.

Comment: You had the right idea but the width of 30px is not wide enough, at least in Firefox.  `position: relative` in the header is okay but it depends on whether the social media icons should be pinned to the page or the header, design choice.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the width of `div#socmed`:

```
#socmed{
    width: auto;
    height: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    top:8px;
    right: 40px;
}
```

Originally, you set width to 25px, and this was not wide enough to show your icons.

Answer (score 0):

This question from:

```
ul, ol {
  margin: 0 0 10px 25px; // to margin:0
  padding: 0;
}
```

please don't in the ul,ol such values `margin: 0 0 10px 25px;` It is a gobal.

Comment: This line appears to be in the bootstrap CSS file, so it is possible that the OP was not fully aware of the implications.

Answer (score 0):

I have put `relative` div in `relative` container. It worked.